# Nhibernate linq fetch in subclass

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, subclass

Help me, please, solve one problem.

I have project, which uses Nhibernate and Fluent Nhibernate. There I created one base class 
(it is not real classes, but they describe my situation):

```
public class Document
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Account Acc { get; private set; }
}
```

And mapping for it:

```
public class DocumentMap: ProfileEntityMap<Document>
{
    public DocumentMap()
    {
        Id(m => m.Id);
        References(m => m.Acc);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
    }
}
```

Then I implemented subclass:

```
public class PaymentDocument: Document
{
    public virtual Card AccountCard { get; set;}
}
```

Mapping for class PaymentDocument:

```
public class PaymentDocumentMap : SubclassMap<PaymentDocument>
{
    public PaymentDocumentMap()
    {
        References(t => t.AccountCard);
    }
}
```

And after that I try execute this query:

```
payments = session.Query<PaymentDocument>()
    .Fetch(t => t.Acc)
    .Fetch(t => t.AccountCard)
    .ToList();
```

And when I insert first fetch I get next exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can somebody answer me where is a problem?

Comment: have you set any breakpoint and debug your code?

Comment: I comment row with .Fetch(t => t.Acc). Query executes with out it. Exception happens in NHibernate source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it was a [bug](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2277) fixed in 3.0.0.Alpha2. Right now it works with the trunk.